# How to have a web service class to call in Async way?

Tags: android, web-services, android-asynctask

I have a web service class to call my web methods. but this have to be called in AsyncTask class. Currently I have an AsyncTask class in all of my activities to call my web service methods. is it possible to mix them (Web service class And AsyncTask) to have a web service class which takes the name of web method and return the result after executing?

This is my web service class:

```
package ClassLibrary;

public class WebService {
    private String namespace="";
    private String url="";

    public WebService(String namespace,String url) {
        super();
        this.namespace = namespace;
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String CallMethod(String methodName,PropertyInfo pi) {
        String result = "default";
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(namespace, methodName);
        request.addProperty(pi);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(url);
        try {
            androidHttpTransport.call(namespace+methodName, envelope);
            SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
            result= response.toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

This is how I'm accessing in AsyncTask:

```
private class AsyncCallWS extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    private ProgressDialog dialog;
    private Activity activity;
    public String wsOutput="";
    public String methodName="";
    private WebService ws;

    public AsyncCallWS(Activity activity,String methodName) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.dialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
        this.methodName = methodName;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        ws = new WebService(PublicVariable.NAMESPACE, PublicVariable.URL);
        PropertyInfo pi= new PropertyInfo();
        pi.setName("UserID");
        pi.setValue("1");
        pi.setType(String.class);
        wsOutput=ws.CallMethod("GetPersonalInfo", pi);

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        if (this.dialog.isShowing()) {
            this.dialog.dismiss();
        }

        if (methodName == "GetPersonalInfo") {
            Log.d("Ehsan","OUTPUT IS:"+ wsOutput);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: instead of an AsyncTask consider AsyncQueryHandler class

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to add (static?) methods to your WebService class for each webservice method and pass in a listener from the calling Activity which is then called in onPostExecute.

You can then call WebService.doThings(thingsListener) from your Activity, execute the AsyncTask with the according method and react in the provided listener to the result...

Answer (score 0):

When I faced same problem, I did:

1. implemented all api calls as `static` methods. They are called in synchronous manner by
2. an `IntentService` descendant, who calls api and then
3. `IntentService` broadcasts results as intents. Interested activities subscribe for events from this `IntentService`

To make activities independent of network operations, consider using a db,a `ContentProvider` or some other storage mechanism, so may take all benefits of `LoaderManager` etc. This approach will cost you some time, but architecture will benefit from it greatly.

Comment: in that case it is better to combine ContentProvider with AsyncQueryHandler, that way not only query will be executed async but also update, delete and insert

Comment: You can get this information by implementing the anonymous interface which will return the result in doInbackground.